# Data e Hora em formato Datetime

Tags: php, datetime

Como faço para concatenar estas duas variáveis para ficar no formato ISO
(Y-m-d H:i:s)?

```
$data = '17-04-2018';
$hora = '16:12';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

1 - Usamos [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) para converter em [unix timestamp](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix);
2 - Usamos [date()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) para converter esse timestamp para o formato desejado:

```
<?php
$data = '17-04-2018';
$hora = '16:12';

$timestamp = strtotime($data. ' ' .$hora);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp); // 2018-04-17 16:12:00
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/iBRoif)

Comment: Funcionou muito bem. Obrigado pela demonstração.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar essas duas funções:

date_create http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-create.php

date_format http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-format.php

```
$data = '17-04-2018';
$hora = '16:12';

$date = date_create($data . $hora);
$result = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

att,

Comment: Tanto esta como a outra resposta funcionaram perfeitamente. Obrigado

Answer (score -4):

tenho uma função ótima aqui, caso alguém necessite.

```
function formatadata($data){
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
return strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y %H:%M:%S' , strtotime($data));}
```

Comment: Esse código não responde a pergunta o usuário quer saber como concatenar duas strings para formar um timestamp.